# How does combiner in Stream.collect method work in java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I created simple demo :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("adf", "bcd", "abc", "hgr", "jyt", "edr", "biu");

String collect = list2.stream().collect(String::new, (res, elem) -> {
              res=res.concat(" ").concat(elem);
//            System.out.printf("res=%s, elem=%s\n", res.isEmpty(), elem);

        }, (res1, res2) -> {
            System.out.printf("res1=%s, res2=%s\n", res1, res2);            
        });
        System.out.println("collect=" + collect);
}
```

The problem is that `BiConsumer combiner` part of `collect` doesn't run at all.

It runs if I use `parallelStream()` but two arguments `res1` and `res2` are equal to supplier `String::new`.

How to make `combiner` work in `collect` method?

Comment: As a note, if you want to join elements by a separator, use `.collect(Collectors.joining(" "));` or `String.join(" ", list2)` if you have a list of strings.

Comment: Note that your attempt is more like *reduce* as you are working with immutable `String`s: `list2.stream().reduce("", (res, elem) -> res.concat(" ").concat(elem))`. However, as [@Alexis C. pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29959795/how-does-combiner-in-stream-collect-method-work-in-java-8#comment48041390_29959795), there are already more efficient built-in solutions.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First off, there is no need for the combiner to be executed in a non-parallel stream since there is nothing to combine.

Secondly, your issue stems from using `String::new` and `String.concat`. The accumulator is supposed to modify the first argument by combining the second argument with it but since strings in Java are immutable your code will produce nothing.

```
          res=res.concat(" ").concat(elem);
```

will create a new string and then throw away it. You want to use a StringBuilder instead so you can keep the intermediate results:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("adf", "bcd", "abc", "hgr", "jyt", "edr", "biu");

    String collect = list2.stream().collect(StringBuilder::new, (res, elem) -> {
        res.append(" ").append(elem);
    }, (res1, res2) -> {
        res1.append(res2.toString());
        System.out.printf("res1=%s, res2=%s\n", res1, res2);
    }).toString();
    System.out.println("collect=" + collect);
}
```

This will also work correctly with a parallel stream

> res1= hgr  jyt, res2= jyt
>   res1= bcd  abc, res2= abc
>   res1= adf  bcd  abc, res2= bcd  abc
>   res1= edr  biu, res2= biu
>   res1= hgr  jyt  edr  biu, res2= edr  biu
>   res1= adf  bcd  abc  hgr  jyt  edr  biu, res2= hgr  jyt  edr  biu
>   collect= adf  bcd  abc  hgr  jyt  edr  biu

Comment: As I run this example I see that the combiner works ONLY in a parallel stream (not ALSO) - otherwise in a single stream you get only the execution of the last System.out.println("collect=" + collect);

Comment: @Raniz, why using String::new will cause create a new string and then throw away it?

Comment: It's not `String::new` but `String::concat` that's the issue. The API expects the collector to modify the result _in place_, not to create a new object which is what `String::concat` does since strings are immutable.

Answer (score 9):

It is more interesting result with and without parallel for [Raniz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3182188/raniz) sample:

```
    String collect = list2.stream().collect(StringBuilder::new,
            (res, elem) -> {
                System.out.printf("ACCUMULATE res=%s, elem=%s\n", res, elem);
                res.append(" ").append(elem);
        },
            (res1, res2) -> {
                System.out.printf("COMBINE res1=%s, res2=%s\n", res1, res2);
                res1.append(res2.toString());
            }).toString();
```

**Without** parallel combine never has been called:

```
ACCUMULATE res=, elem=adf
ACCUMULATE res= adf, elem=bcd
ACCUMULATE res= adf bcd, elem=abc
ACCUMULATE res= adf bcd abc, elem=hgr
ACCUMULATE res= adf bcd abc hgr, elem=jyt
ACCUMULATE res= adf bcd abc hgr jyt, elem=edr
ACCUMULATE res= adf bcd abc hgr jyt edr, elem=biu
collect= adf bcd abc hgr jyt edr biu
```

And **with** parallel `list2.stream().parallel()...`:

```
ACCUMULATE res=, elem=jyt
ACCUMULATE res=, elem=hgr
COMBINE res1= hgr, res2= jyt
ACCUMULATE res=, elem=biu
ACCUMULATE res=, elem=edr
COMBINE res1= edr, res2= biu
ACCUMULATE res=, elem=bcd
COMBINE res1= hgr jyt, res2= edr biu
ACCUMULATE res=, elem=abc
ACCUMULATE res=, elem=adf
COMBINE res1= bcd, res2= abc
COMBINE res1= adf, res2= bcd abc
COMBINE res1= adf bcd abc, res2= hgr jyt edr biu
collect= adf bcd abc hgr jyt edr biu
```

Comment: Why are we calling toString method on res2? Is it necessary? I tried to remove it and it worked fine.

Comment: @Alexander if works fine, that not nesessary:) I've taken the solution "as is" from sample above.

Comment: Nice, thank you! What do you mean "with parallel"? Do you mean you used parallelStream for the second example and so it was run multithreaded?

Comment: @aderchox it means `stream().parallel()`

Answer (score 8):

I think that the `combiner` is only used in parallel Streams (to combine the partial outputs of the parallel computations), so make your Stream parallel.

```
String collect = list2.parallelStream().collect(...
```

Comment: See [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html#collect)

Comment: @AlexisC. I think the other part was added after I answered it.

Comment: And nothing prevents you from updating your answer... I think the interesting part is to explain what's the OP did wrong and _"How to make combiner work in collect method?"_ (despite that the accumulator is also wrong)