# What is the use of a combiner in collect function of stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In jdk8，the Stream provide `collect` function with `supplier`,`accumulator` and `combiner`

```
<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,BiConsumer<R, ? super T> accumulator,BiConsumer<R, R> combiner);
```

I see the example in the annotation that transform a String Stream to a String，but I am very confused what the use of combiner in the function signature. I think in the accumulator,the new element has been added to the result continer?

I have tried give the combiner a null value，but I got a null pointer exception.

```
 Stream<String> stringStream = Stream.of("hello", "world", "morning");
 String string = stringStream.collect(StringBuilder::new, 
 StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append).toString();
 System.out.println(string);
```

Comment: seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29959795/how-does-combiner-in-stream-collect-method-work-in-java-8

Comment: `supplier + accumulator` is mandatory for sequential collecting. `combiner` is for parallel collecting. It's optional for sequential stream. If you don't want to provide it, you can throw a RuntimeException like `(a,b)->{throw new RuntimeException();}`. You cannot throw a regular unchecked exception. You cannot set it to null (which is puzzling for me as well)

Comment: Javadoc explains a bit why you receive a NPE, the goal is that collect can be interchangeable between sequential and parallel stream without problem `<p>Like {@link #reduce(Object, BinaryOperator)}, {@code collect} operations
     * can be parallelized without requiring additional synchronization.`

Answer (score 3):

**Combiner :** Combiner works in parallel processing, to combine the two values compatible with accumulator

```
collect(Supplier supplier, BiConsumer accumulator, BiConsumer combiner)
```

**supplier :** It creates a new result container which will be populated by accumulator and combiner and finally it will be returned by `collect()` method. In parallel processing the Supplier function will be called multiple times that will return fresh value each time.

**accumulator :** It incorporates additional element into the result.

**combiner :** It combines two values that must be compatible with accumulator. Combiner works in parallel processing.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Mukesh", "Vishal", "Amar");
    String result = list.parallelStream().collect(StringBuilder::new,
            (response, element) -> response.append(" ").append(element),
            (response1, response2) -> response1.append(",").append(response2.toString()))
            .toString();
    System.out.println("Result: " + result);
```

**Output :**

```
Result:  Mukesh, Vishal, Amar
```

If we use `list.stream()` then the output will be different because it is not parallel processing and so nothing to combine.

**Output :**

```
Result:  Mukesh Vishal Amar
```