# Java Stream GroupBy and Reduce

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors, groupingby, reducing

I have an Item class which contains a code, quantity and amount fields, and a list of items which may contain many items (with same code). I want to group the items by code and sum up their quantities and amounts.

I was able to achieve half of it using stream's `groupingBy` and `reduce`. The grouping by worked, but the reduce is reducing all of the grouped items into one single item repeated over the different codes (`groupingBy` key).

Shouldn't reduce here reduce the list of items for each code from the map? Why is it retuning the same combined item for all.

Below is a sample code.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.Map;

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Item> itemList = Arrays.asList(
            createItem("CODE1", 1, 12),
            createItem("CODE2", 4, 22),
            createItem("CODE3", 5, 50),
            createItem("CODE4", 2, 11),
            createItem("CODE4", 8, 20),
            createItem("CODE2", 1, 42)
        );
        
        Map<String, Item> aggregatedItems = itemList
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Item::getCode,
                Collectors.reducing(new Item(), (aggregatedItem, item) -> {
                    int aggregatedQuantity = aggregatedItem.getQuantity();
                    double aggregatedAmount = aggregatedItem.getAmount();
                    
                    aggregatedItem.setQuantity(aggregatedQuantity + item.getQuantity());
                    aggregatedItem.setAmount(aggregatedAmount + item.getAmount());
                    
                    return aggregatedItem;
                })
            ));
        
        System.out.println("Map total size: " + aggregatedItems.size()); // expected 4
        System.out.println();
        aggregatedItems.forEach((key, value) -> {
            System.out.println("key: " + key);
            System.out.println("value - quantity: " + value.getQuantity() + " - amount: " + value.getAmount());
            System.out.println();
        });
    }
    
    private static Item createItem(String code, int quantity, double amount) {
        Item item = new Item();
        item.setCode(code);
        item.setQuantity(quantity);
        item.setAmount(amount);
        return item;
    }
}

class Item {
    private String code;
    private int quantity;
    private double amount;
    
    public Item() {
        quantity = 0;
        amount = 0.0;
    }
    
    public String getCode() { return code; }
    public int getQuantity() { return quantity; }
    public double getAmount() { return amount; }
    
    public void setCode(String code) { this.code = code; }
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) { this.quantity = quantity; }
    public void setAmount(double amount) { this.amount = amount; }
}
```

and below is the output.

```
Map total size: 4

key: CODE2
value - quantity: 21 - amount: 157.0

key: CODE1
value - quantity: 21 - amount: 157.0

key: CODE4
value - quantity: 21 - amount: 157.0

key: CODE3
value - quantity: 21 - amount: 157.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must *not* modify the input arguments to `Collectors.reducing`. `new Item()` is only executed once and all your reduction operations will share the same "aggregation instance". In other words: the map will contain the same value instance 4 times (you can easily check yourself with `System.identityHashCode()` or by comparing for reference-equality: `aggregatedItems.get("CODE1") == aggregatedItems.get("CODE2")`).

Instead, return a new result instance:

```
        final Map<String, Item> aggregatedItems = itemList
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Item::getCode,
                Collectors.reducing(new Item(), (item1, item2) -> {
                    final Item reduced = new Item();
                    reduced.setQuantity(item1.getQuantity() + item2.getQuantity());
                    reduced.setAmount(item1.getAmount() + item2.getAmount());
                    return reduced;
                })
            ));
```

Output:

```
Map total size: 4

key: CODE2
value - quantity: 5 - amount: 64.0

key: CODE1
value - quantity: 1 - amount: 12.0

key: CODE4
value - quantity: 10 - amount: 31.0

key: CODE3
value - quantity: 5 - amount: 50.0
```

Answer (score 4):

## Mutable reduction vs Immutable reduction

In this case, `Collectors.reducing()` isn't the right tool because it meant for **immutable reduction**, i.e. for performing folding operation in which every reduction step results in creation of a **new** immutable object.

But instead of generating a new object at each reduction step, you're changing the state of the object provided as an *identity*.

As a consequence, you're getting an incorrect result because the *identity* object would be created only **once** per thread. This single instance of the `Item` is used for accumulation, and reference to it end up in every value of the map.

More elaborate information you can find in the *Stream API documentation*, specifically in these parts: [*Reduction*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction) and [*Mutable Reduction*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction).

And here's a short quote explaining how `Stream.reduce()` works (the mechanism behind `Collectors.reducing()` is the same):

> The **accumulator function** takes a partial result and the next element, and produces a **new partial result**.

## Use mutable reduction

The problem can be fixed by generating a new instance of `Item` while accumulating *values* mapped to the same *key* with, but a more performant approach would be to use **mutable reduction** instead.

For that, you can implement a *custom collector* created via static method [`Collector.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...)):

```
Map<String, Item> aggregatedItems = itemList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Item::getCode,
        Collector.of(
            Item::new,   // mutable container of the collector
            Item::merge, // accumulator - defines how stream data should be accumulated
            Item::merge  // combiner - mergin the two containers while executing stream in parallel
        )
    ));
```

For convenience, you can introduce method `merge()` responsible for accumulating properties of the two *items*. It would allow to avoid repeating the same logic in *accumulator* and *combiner*, and keep the collector implementation lean and well-readable.

```
public class Item {
    private String code;
    private int quantity;
    private double amount;
    
    // getters, constructor, etc.
    
    public Item merge(Item other) {
        this.quantity += other.quantity;
        this.amount += other.amount;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `reducing`, which assumes that you won't mutate the accumulator passed in. `reducing` won't create new `Item`s for you for each new group, and expects you to create new `Item`s and return them in the lambda, like this:

```
// this works as expected
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    Item::getCode,
    Collectors.reducing(new Item(), (item1, item2) -> createItem(
        item1.getCode(),
        item1.getQuantity() + item2.getQuantity(),
        item1.getAmount() + item2.getAmount()
    ))
));
```

so it is very suitable if you are using immutable objects like numbers or strings.

Since you are not creating new `Item`s in your code, `reducing` keeps on reusing that same instance, resulting in the behaviour you see.

If you want to mutate the objects, you can do mutable reduction in a thread safe way with `Collector.of`:

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    Item::getCode,
    Collector.of(Item::new, (aggregatedItem, item) -> {
        int aggregatedQuantity = aggregatedItem.getQuantity();
        double aggregatedAmount = aggregatedItem.getAmount();

        aggregatedItem.setQuantity(aggregatedQuantity + item.getQuantity());
        aggregatedItem.setAmount(aggregatedAmount + item.getAmount());
    }, (item1, item2) -> createItem(
        item1.getCode(),
        item1.getQuantity() + item2.getQuantity(),
        item1.getAmount() + item2.getAmount()
    ))
));
```

Notice that you now pass the reference to `Item`'s constructor, i.e. a way to create new `Item`s when necessary, as opposed to just a single `new Item()`. In addition, you also provide a third argument, the combiner, that tells the collector how to create a new item from two existing ones, which will be used if this collector is used in a concurrent situation. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29959795/5133585) for more info about the combiner)

This contrast between `Collector.of` and `Collectors.reducing` is the same contrast between `Stream.reduce` and `Stream.collect`. [Learn more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22577274/5133585).